# Not getting a filled array in unit testing (sepc.ts) from (.ts) file

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, angular-test

I want to get this all appointments array in apec.ts file with its filled objects, but when I am directly calling it by component.allAppoitments its getting allAppoitments with zero elements filled, how can i get this array with all element filled in spec.ts file

spec.ts file ======>

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DashboardComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.getAppointments();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("all appoitments added",()=>{
    expect(component.allAppointment.length).toEqual(0);
  });
```

.ts file ======>

```
 allAppointment: AppointmentModel []=[];
 appointmentSummary:any[]=[];



  ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.getAppointments()

  
    this.getAppointmentsSummary();
  }

  
  getAppointments(){
    this.dashboardService.getAllPatients().subscribe((res: any) => {
      for(let r of res){
        this.allAppointment.push(r)
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: You'll need to mock the `dashboardService`.

Comment: ... just self-ask - what else could be as a result ... ie, you have an asynchronous method of some service (dashboardService with method Returning Observable) => so you need, so to say, to "await" on it (in terms of Promises for simplicity) => so, go Subscribe to the Observable and expect results (if it actually integration test of kinds... otherwise, if it's a unit-test, mock it) : https://github.com/VovanSuper/accordion-simple/blob/master/projects/%40ngx-dummy/accordion-simple/src/lib/accordion-item.component.spec.ts#L66